# Jenkins Job DSL Issue

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have created the following groovy script to create a sample job in Jenkins.

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.node_monitors.*
import hudson.slaves.*
import java.util.concurrent.*
jenkins = Hudson.instance

now=Calendar.instance;
def project_name = 'ARCHIE_DSL_TEST'

println("The build is run at ${now.time}");

freeStyleJob(project_name) {
        disabled(false)
        logRotator(-1, 10)
        description("Our first DSL Generated ServerSpec Job")
        parameters {
                choiceParam("SERVER_FQDN", ["server1.test.com.au", "server2.test.com.au", "server3.test.com.au", "server4.test.com.au"])
                description 'Select a server from the list to test'
        }
        scm {
                git {
                        remote {
                                github("MY_ORG/my_repo", 'ssh', 'github.aus.mydomain.com')
                                branch("*/master")
                        }
                }
        }
        triggers {
                scm("H/15 * * * *")
        }
        steps {
        }
}
```

When I create a job in Jenkins to run this DSL, it works fine and create a job called ARCHIE_DSL_TEST.

However what I'd like to do is run this job using curl and I've been running the following command.

```
/usr/bin/curl -k --user 'archie' --data-urlencode "script=$(</var/lib/jenkins/jobs/archie_test/workspace/create_tab.groovy)" https://localhost:8080/scriptText
```

However then it gives me an exception.

> The build is run at Wed Jan 27 16:54:20 AEDT 2016
>   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   Script1.freeStyleJob() is applicable for argument types:
>   (java.lang.String, Script1$_run_closure1) values: [ARCHIE_DSL_TEST,
>   Script1$_run_closure1@9761fdb]    at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:78)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
>     at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:13)   at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:580)    at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:618)    at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:589)    at
>   hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:139)
>     at
>   hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:111)
>     at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)  at
>   hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics.executeGroovy(RemotingDiagnostics.java:108)
>     at jenkins.model.Jenkins._doScript(Jenkins.java:3556)   at
>   jenkins.model.Jenkins.doScriptText(Jenkins.java:3540)     at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor205.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)    at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:121)   at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:123)
>     at
>   hudson.plugins.greenballs.GreenBallFilter.doFilter(GreenBallFilter.java:59)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:120)
>     at
>   com.smartcodeltd.jenkinsci.plugin.assetbundler.filters.LessCSS.doFilter(LessCSS.java:46)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:120)
>     at
>   hudson.plugins.audit_trail.AuditTrailFilter.doFilter(AuditTrailFilter.java:95)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:120)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:114)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
>     at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
>     at
>   hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.success(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:140)
>     at
>   jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:82)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
>     at
>   hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
>     at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:168)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
>     at
>   hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:949)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1011)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:651)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.handle(SslConnection.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
>     at
>   winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

What am I doing wrong here?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straight-forward way to do what you want is:

- Create a Jenkins job with "Process Job DSL" build step that loads your create_tabs.groovy from SCM
- Enable the "Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)" build triggers option in the job
- Trigger that job through curl, e.g. `curl http://someserver/job/dsl_job/build`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [REST API Runner](https://github.com/sheehan/job-dsl-gradle-example#rest-api-runner) from the Job DSL Gradle Example to create or update jobs through the Jenkins REST API.